# Does a (nice) centerless group always have a centerless profinite completion?

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

This is an extension of a question I asked [here on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3251019/274352)

---

Assume that I have a finitely generated residually finite centerless group $G$. Is it true that the profinite completion $\hat{G}$ also has trivial center?

In the linked question, user YCor was able to show that this **fails** in general if you do not assume either finite generation or residually finite. However, the result happens to be true if $G$ is a surface group. I’d like to know if this is a phenomenon specific to surface groups, or if this is a more general fact.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is No in general. Let $n\geq 3$ be odd (it is not necessary that $n$ be odd) and suppose $G=\mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z})$. There exists a subgroup $\Gamma \subset \mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z})$ of finite index which is torsion-free and centreless (the centre can only be $\pm 1$ and because $n$ is odd the centre can only be trivial). However, $\mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z})$ has the congruence subgroup property which means that we have the following inclusion of the profinite completions:

$$\widehat {\mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z})}= \prod _{q \; \mathrm{prime}} \mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z}_q)\supset \widehat {\Gamma} \supset \prod _{p\in S} U_p \times \prod _{ \ell \notin S}  \mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z}_\ell),$$
where $S$ is a finite set of primes, $U_p$ is an open subgroup of finite index in $\mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z}_p)$, and $\ell$ runs through primes in the complement of $S$. Since for infinitely many $\ell$ (for example, all $\ell$ with $\ell\equiv 1 \; (\mathrm{mod}\;n)$), the group $\mathrm{SL}_n({\mathbb Z}_\ell)$ has $n$-th roots of unity in the centre, it follows that the profinite completion of $\Gamma $ is not centreless.

Comment: Great. It seems to work for every finite index subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ when $n$ is odd, including $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ itself (and for all centerless finite index subgroups, for arbitrary $n\ge 3$).

Comment: @YCor: thanks for the comment. Yes, torsion free is not assumed by the OP, so it works for every finite index subgroup if $n\geq 3$ is odd.